# not receiving emails sent in form from my server - wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, forms, email, smtp, hosting

I have a website hosted in bluehost, and my domain is managed elsewhere. the domain is pointing to my host with IP a record (and not NS).

I have several forms in my website, on submit they are being sent to multiple email addresses, and email addresses under my domain  ("mydomain.com") are not received.

Other mails on other domain are being received with no special issue.

When I install SMTP plugin in WordPress (currently using WP Mail SMTP) I can enable one email address that will be the sender ("info@mydomain.com") and it works.

but i have several forms that need to be sent from different email addresses -
for one form it needs to "info@mydomain.com",
for another form it needs to be "support@mydomain.com", etc.

Why does this happen? and how can I solve this? how can I make my email provider (gsuit gmail) accept all email addresses under my domain? 
(changing the NS is not an option)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the forms on your website being handled via a 3rd party plugin? If so, you may need to dive deeper into said plugin and see how they are handling the sending of the email. Often times 3rd party plugins will use phpmail() to send emails, and some hosts block this functionality to reduce email spam coming from their server. This happens often on shared hosting servers.

Comment: I don't think that this is the issue, since emails are received in emails that are not under the same domain as the site